# Higher Dimensional Analogues of the Mountain Climbing Problem

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Let us call a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to itself that fixes $0$ and $1$, a B-function. The Mountain Climbing Problem presents us with two B-functions $f,g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, and asks when there exist B-functions $h$ and $j$ such that $f\circ h=g\circ j$. This has been answered in many cases, for example, if $f$ and $g$ are locally non-constant such functions exist. I'm wondering if there is a higher-dimensional version of this problem, although the mountain climbing analogy disappears. Let us call a continuous function from $B^n$, the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, to itself, a B-function if it fixes the boundary $S^{n-1}$. Given two B-functions $f$ and $g$ on $B^n$, are there results on when B-functions $h$ and $j$ exist such that $f\circ h=g\circ j$?